# How to create a "none of the above" label in a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I am working a simple image classification. Each object  must fit in one of the categories based on its material (aluminum, iron, copper) 
There is only one picture for each class, e.g. all aluminum materials don't appear in the same photo along with iron materials for example. The model is working pretty well and the accuracy is great. However I don't know how to handle images that don't fit any of these 3 categories. Let's say I submit a picture of a piece of wood. This obliviously don't fit in any of the 3 categories, but my model seems to "guess" one of them and give one of these random categories a false positive along with a high probability. I understand the result of model.predict() cannot be zero,  the ideal scenario.  I have tested both softmax and sigmoid activations to no avail. I also tried to create a bogus category called "none" and trained the model with random photos of objects that do not have any of the aforementioned materials. The result was the whole model to become unreliable and lost most of the accuracy I had before.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))


model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(classes, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 


              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='c:/Users/data/models/model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5',save_best_only=True)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint] 

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=75,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid), callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Comment: You can set a threshold. If the confidence of the model is above that threshold, then you let the model predict from the 3 categories, else predict as "Other". It cant be done automatically. If you want, then you will need to train the model with 4 classes, 3 for your required and 4th one for others.

Comment: Thank you Vivek. Problem is the model does get me very high confidence for the wrong categorization. Here is the what model.predict() retrieves:
    c:/users/data/wood.jpg ---------------------
    Aluminum: 99.99147653579712%
    Other 2.371654261867917e-08%
    Iron: 0.008510933548677713%
   Copper: 2.7863444884701494e-07%

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this is almost impossible with supervised learning.

Supervised learning takes some dataset and let the machine learn. However the category that falls under "none" is simply too much. It is almost impossible to cover all other materials under the category of none. Worst is that supervised learning will mostly recognize what had been trained. so when a completely new stuff appears in your testing. it is very likely, the system will ignore or give one of the result based on the given training.

One approach that is more suitable in your application is unsupervised learning. There should be many resources and researches in using unsupervised learning for image classification. One of the sample paper:

https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2013/papers/Siva_Looking_Beyond_the_2013_CVPR_paper.pdf

Any feedback is welcomed. I stand corrected. Thank you

Comment: @beponto , fixed the link, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add yet another class which you will label items not matching your existing labels. So you have aluminum, iron, copper and none_of_the_above

Change your model in line:

```
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='sigmoid'))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(classes+1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

And modify your data to label wood as none_of_the_above. You will need a lot of examples that do not match aluminum, iron, copper.

Now add custom accuracy:

```
def ignore_accuracy_of_class(class_to_ignore=0):
    def ignore_acc(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true_class = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
        y_pred_class = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)

        ignore_mask = K.cast(K.not_equal(y_pred_class, class_to_ignore), 'int32')
        matches = K.cast(K.equal(y_true_class, y_pred_class), 'int32') * ignore_mask
        accuracy = K.sum(matches) / K.maximum(K.sum(ignore_mask), 1)
        return accuracy

    return ignore_acc
```

and add it to compile:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy', ignore_accuracy_of_class(4)])
```

4 in ignore_accuracy_of_class is a label to ignore. Now you have both accuracy of the whole model and accuracy for only your selected aluminum, iron, copper labels.

Comment: Hey, I would like to use your idea. But I can't get it to work. If I implement it like you did, it gives an error saying that one input is expected but two were given. If I delete the class_to_ignore input, it just gives 0 back for all samples??? It seems like, that no information is passed to the ignore_acc function. Do you have an idea how to solve this?